# The differential equation $(D^2+1)y=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation $(D^2+1)y=0$, $D$ is differential operator and  $y(0)=1 , y(\pi)=0$
has

**A**. unique solution

**B**. Single infinite family of solutions

**C**. No solution

**D**. Doubly infinite family of solutions

I obtained solution as $y(x)=c_1 \cos x+c_2 \sin x$ .

How do I choose correct option?

Comment: Your solution is correct. Now just use boundary conditions to see if you can solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$. You will see that it leads to inconsistency and hence $C$ is the correct choice - No solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation need not be solved given what the question actually wants. It does not require the equation to be solved.

The given differential equation is of $2$nd order and hence its general solution, as you have written, contains two arbitrary constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

To find the $2$ constants definitively, you need $2$ boundary conditions. And those two conditions are given as follows:

> $$y(0)=1$$  $$y(\pi)=0$$

So you can determine the $2$ constants and what you then have is **a unique solution**.

Hence the correct answer *should have been in general* OPTION **A**.

BUT observe that here the $2$ conditions do not allow the $2$ constants to be determined. Moreover it causes an indeterminacy in the value of $c_1$. Hence this equation in particular has **no solution**.

> Hence the correct answer *is* OPTION **C**.

Comment: My second equation is  $0 = -1 + c_2(0)$ and $c_! = 1$.

Comment: isn not there is inconsistency in second equation $0=-1$

Comment: @DunVatta Yes there is. I have mentioned that in my answer.